# Update external page upon form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a site that amongst other things needs to update outputted data on page A (without the user refreshing manually) when a form is submitted on page B. I want to avoid `HTML meta refresh` and likewise I would ideally like to avoid an `AJAX` request that pokes the server every 10 seconds querying the database and updating the values. It seems unnecessarily inefficient to query the database six times a minute when it's likely the user will only update their data once a day, if that.

With that in mind, what I would like to achieve is something like the below:

-

1. A user fills out a form and presses submit on page B
2. Page A has a listen request (or page B has a push request) that says "I've just
   received new data" / "I've just sent new data"
3. Page A recognising this request then queries the database and updates the data on the page accordingly

-

We avoid querying six times a minute and bandwidth isn't eaten alive. The problem is I have absolutely no idea where to start with this, and my experience with AJAX goes as far as sending through three data variables to then delete a record in a table.

Many thanks.

Comment: Unless you have the ability to use persistent socket server keeping track of live events and exposing them to websockets, repeated Ajax calls is your only option.

Comment: Roger that, I thought this would end up being the most likely case... I guess with that in mind I will try and work up something that checks the latest submit time against the current time and then querying the database based upon that response. Anyway, thanks for your comment!